# BeautifulSoup and removing results from a list? python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to remove items from a list I created from some BeautifulSoup results. My for loop seems to remove some of the items - but not all - that match my criteria in the if and elif conditions.  Can you guys help me out?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

# url constructor for search
pass
pass
pass

# read the site into a string
site = urllib.urlopen("http://losangeles.craigslist.org/moa/")
html = site.read()
site.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)



#Price
prices = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"itempp"})
prices = [str(j).strip('<span class="itempp"> $</span>') for j in prices]
print prices
print len(prices)

for k in prices:
    if k == '':
        prices.remove(k)
    elif int(k) <= 50:
        prices.remove(k)

print prices
print len(prices)
```

returns:

```
['230', '120', '1', '333', '180', '380', '120', '1', '230', '25', '300', '500', '480', '199', '600', '180', '260', '200', '35', '250', '10', '80', '200', '20', '20', '', '20', '15', '10', '', '35', '225', '9', '', '79', '280', '30', '10', '10', '80', '1', '20', '', '15', '20', '200', '550', '20', '700', '350', '25', '30', '99', '', '', '40', '', '200', '25', '20', '180', '', '120', '50', '700', '120', '380', '320', '130', '325', '175', '180', '120', '260', '5', '450', '650', '400', '700', '50', '600', '250', '699', '245', '649', '450', '615', '450', '665', '5', '5', '50', '1100', '30', '300', '700', '15', '12', '12', '10']
100
['230', '120', '333', '180', '380', '120', '230', '300', '500', '480', '199', '600', '180', '260', '200', '250', '80', '200', '35', '225', '79', '280', '10', '10', '80', '20', '20', '200', '550', '20', '700', '350', '99', '', '', '200', '20', '180', '', '120', '700', '120', '380', '320', '130', '325', '175', '180', '120', '260', '450', '650', '400', '700', '600', '250', '699', '245', '649', '450', '615', '450', '665', '5', '1100', '30', '300', '700', '15', '12', '10']
71
```

**note that the first 1 has been removed, but then some 10's remain, and so do some ''s.

Thanks guys

Comment: This is my first go at BeautifulSoup - I hope I'm not missing something obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over a copy of the list `prices` if you want to remove some items during the loop. Try:

```
for k in prices[:]:
    if k == '':
        prices.remove(k)
    elif int(k) <= 50:
        prices.remove(k)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
prices[:] = [p for p in prices if p and int(p) > 50]
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas - I just learned that in class, too.  I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me!!